# How can I create a windows 10 script which runs a command under specified path?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I created a npmruns.bat file with a content:

```
C:\myfolder>npm run s
```

I wanted to create a script file which run a command: `npm run s` under specified location: `C:\myfolder` , but it doesn't work. I run it by double click (I have an admin rights).

I tried to create a script which can be executed from any location (other than `C:\myfolder`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pushd` and `cd /d` will be the options for this:

```
@echo off
pushd "C:\myfolder"
call npm.cmd run s
popd
```

This will `push` to the path of the `batch-file` as the working directory, `popd` is not required if you do not need to go back to the starting working directory, which as admin, will be `"%systemroot%\system32"`

Alternatively you can run:

```
cd /d "c:\myfolder"
```